# How to chart data within a website hosted on Amazon S3

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, d3.js, amazon-s3

I have a static website that is hosted on an AWS S3 bucket.  I want to be able to put visualizations on the website using data pulled from an s3 bucket.  It is to my understanding that sites on S3 must be static.  Can I still pull data from an S3 bucket and visualize it using D3.js or will it no longer be static?  Is there a better data visualization tool to use that would work better?

Note:  I am very unfamiliar with the difference between static and dynamic sites.  This site just needs simple visualizations from data that is pulled when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The static vs dynamic difference means no server-side rendering (php, java, python, etc.). It just serves files as is to the browser, so they have to be readable by the browser (html, css, javascript).

D3 will work. You will just need to get the bucket data via ajax using the S3 Rest API:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/Welcome.html.

Here is the SDK for the browser:
https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-browser/

Comment: There's really no need for the SDK in this case.  Simple use of the Fetch API or XHR works well.

Comment: Thanks this was super helpful!